# Minor change results in "unknown" - related to quantifier preprocessing?

Tags: z3

The following "minimal" program, distilled from a much larger program, *is expected to yield* `unsat` (and does). However, uncommenting the additional conjunct in the quantifier `AX-1` changes the result to `unknown` (in Z3 4.5.0 x64 on Windows 10).

```
(set-option :auto_config false)
(set-option :smt.mbqi false)

(declare-fun foo (Int) Bool)
(declare-const k Real)

(assert (forall ((i Int)) (!
  (and
    (< 0.0 k)
    ; (implies (<= 0 i) (< 0.0 k)) ;;; ---- uncomment this line ----
  )
  :pattern ((foo i))
  :qid |AX-1|)))

(assert (forall ((i Int)) (!
  (foo i)
  :pattern ((foo i))
  :qid |AX-2|)))

(declare-const j Int)
(assert (< j 0))

; (push) ;;; doesn't make a difference
(assert (not
  (ite
    (foo j)
    (< 0.0 k)
    false)))

; (set-option :smt.qi.profile true)
(check-sat)
; (get-info :all-statistics)
; (pop)
```

The quantifier instantiation statistics show that `AX-2` is instantiated in both cases, but `AX-1` is only instantiated if the additional conjunct is *not* included. My assumption is that in the latter case, Z3 eliminates the quantifier since the quantified variable doesn't occur in the body.

However, I find it surprising that the version *with* the additional conjunct - in which Z3 presumably *doesn't* eliminate the quantifier - yields `unknown`, since the trigger for the quantifier (`(foo j)`) should be available.

**Question:** Is this behaviour expected - and if so, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed as a bug, see [Github issue 935](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/935).